# Can't login to EC2 after changing the login user and port

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

Due to the client's requirement, we changed the login user and port to login into the ec2 shell.
e.g. it looked like this:> ssh -i 'key.pem' changed_user@ip -p 2002.

I created a snapshot out of it and then created ami. Now when I have made a new ec2 instance from the ami, it's not allowing to login.
1.I tried with/without mentioning the port.
2.With/without the changed_username.
3.Tried with different keys too.

What should I do to login? Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you add the your ssh public key to the new user home folder?

Comment: Yes, in the main instance. But the new instance from ami is not allowing to enter into the shell.

Comment: You can try using web ssh console - easy connect or ssm session manager.

Comment: Thank you Marcin for the reply. It's not allowing to connect with either of the users. And for ssm, I think it needs to be installed first in the machine, then you can access it.

Comment: Can you guide, what steps should I follow whenever the user and port changes are done next time?

Comment: Depending on the AMI, SSM is pre-installed on standard AWS AMIs. So you only need to attach a role to your instance with SSM permissions.

Comment: Did you allow inbound connections on port 2002 in your network security group?

Comment: yes, I think it's not taking the user. I changed it to web from ec2-user. Now the new instance is not taking user: web, ec2-user or root.

Comment: When you launched the new EC2 instance, you indicated the relevant keypair name, yes? I recommend enabling [Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html#ic-prerequisites) on an instance then capture a new AMI. so that you can use instance connect to SSH for debugging.

Comment: I will try this once and keep you guys updated about the happenings.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for my query. So here I am sharing it.

1. Create a new EC2 instance from AMI in the same VPC as the original(EC2 used to create AMI).
2. There will be 2 selections for the subnet in the launch section. By default private subnet is selected. Change it to the **public** subnet.
   3.In the same screen, select **auto IP = enabled**( by default it is disabled).
3. Choose any instance type and create an instance with SSH 22 enabled.
4. You can only log in to the new EC2 instance when you enter the **same details** as you accessed the original instance.
5. My case -> Eg: ***ssh -i original-key.pem changed_user@ip -p 2002***